# MySql workbench not responding w local server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, localserver

I have been using MySql Workbench to connect to a local MySql server and to remote MySql Servers. The last couple of days the Workbench freezes when I connect to the local version. It still works for the remote servers.

I am using workbench 6.3.4 and then tried 6.2.5 just to see if it is a version issue.

I also can access the local MySql instance using HeidiSQL.

Any recommendations on what to look for?

**Update**
The advice to recreate the connection solved the issue. I just created a new one and it works fine.

Comment: Which OS/Server/versions are you using ?

Comment: sshh! @SaehunSeanOh, he has the `not-responding` tag set.

Comment: I'm hella confused. EDIT: GOT IT :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things you can try:

- Try restarting the sql server (remember, workbench is just a utility for accessing a db, it does not host the database for you)
- See if you can access mysql on the command prompt / terminal, the command for mac & windows

(once you navigate to the mysql folder, try the command:)

```
mysql -u root
```

(if you have a password-protected account, the command will be

```
mysql -u someuser -p
```

- If the above doesn't work, mysql is either offline or denying you access (depending on response), and you'll need to setup the server / assign privileges.
- If all else fails, it may help to try another version of SQL / Workbench (for a easy-to-use sql sever setup, I'd recommend WAMP or MAMP, assuming you want a HTTP server bundled with it)

Additionally, it may help to recreate the local connection in workbench (of if your getting regular crashes, reinstall & update workbench). Good luck with it.